# $\frac{3}{4} \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}} \sum_{r=1}^{n}\sqrt{r} }{\sum_{r=1}^{n}r }\right)$

Tags: integration, limits, summation

$$\frac{3}{4} \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}} \sum_{r=1}^{n}\sqrt{r}  }{\sum_{r=1}^{n}r    }\right)$$

Apparently, the answer is 2.

My try:
$$\frac{3}{4} \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{n^2}{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}    }\right)$$

$$\frac{3}{2} \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$

Which is $\frac{3}{2}$. Surely I did something stupid or illegal here. What was it?

Also on the forum where I found this, It was said it can be done by converting into integrals, A push in the right direction on that too would be pretty rad.

Hope I am not asking too much.

Comment: How did you get that $n^2$ for the product of sums involving $\sqrt{r}$? You are claiming that $$
\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }} +  \cdots  + \frac{1}{{\sqrt n }}} \right)\left( {1 + \sqrt 2  +  \cdots  + \sqrt n } \right) = n^2 ?
$$

Comment: A hint: $$
\left( {\sum\limits_{r = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{\sqrt r }}} } \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{r = 1}^n {\sqrt r } } \right) = n^2 \left( {\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{r = 1}^n {\sqrt {\frac{n}{r}} } } \right)\left( {\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{r = 1}^n {\sqrt {\frac{r}{n}} } } \right).
$$ Do you know about Riemann sums for integrals?

Comment: @Gary yea? I remember learning you can group sums together such that $\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}} \sum_{r=1}^{n}\sqrt{r}$ becomes $\sum_{r=1}^{n} \sum_{r=1}^{n}1$

Comment: Are you sure you learnt that? So for example, with $n=2$, $$
\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}} \right)(1 + \sqrt 2 ) = 4?
$$ But also $$
\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}} \right)(1 + \sqrt 2 ) = \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}} \right) + \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}} \right)\sqrt 2  = 2 + \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }} + \sqrt 2 .
$$ The thing is that you should not use $r$ for both summations. Use $m$ for instance for $r$ in the second one to see clearer.

Comment: @Linkin thats only when theye are independent vearibles say $i,j$ but here $\sqrt{r},\sqrt{1/r}$ are dependent

Comment: If you know about generalized harmonic numbers, you could obtain much more than the limit itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using the suggested integral approach. Notice that
\begin{align*}
\frac{{\sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{\sqrt r }}} \sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n {\sqrt r } }}{{\sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n r }} = \frac{{\sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n {\sqrt {\frac{n}{r}} } \sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n {\sqrt {\frac{r}{n}} } }}{{\sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n r }} & = \frac{{\frac{1}{{n^2 }}\sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n {\sqrt {\frac{n}{r}} } \sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n {\sqrt {\frac{r}{n}} } }}{{\frac{1}{{n^2 }}\sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n r }} \\ &= \frac{{\left( {\frac{1}{n}\sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n {\sqrt {\frac{n}{r}} } } \right)\left( {\frac{1}{n}\sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n {\sqrt {\frac{r}{n}} } } \right)}}{{\frac{1}{n}\sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n {\frac{r}{n}} }}.
\end{align*}
Thus, noticing the Riemann sums, we find
\begin{align*}
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{3}{4}\frac{{\sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{\sqrt r }}} \sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n {\sqrt r } }}{{\sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n r }} & = \frac{3}{4}\frac{{\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {\frac{1}{n}\sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n {\sqrt {\frac{n}{r}} } } \right)\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {\frac{1}{n}\sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n {\sqrt {\frac{r}{n}} } } \right)}}{{\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{n}\sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^n {\frac{r}{n}} }} \\ & = \frac{3}{4}\frac{{\int_0^1 {\frac{{dx}}{{\sqrt x }}} \int_0^1 {\sqrt x dx} }}{{\int_0^1 {xdx} }} = 2.
\end{align*}